# How to import SQL Server Compact database into Oracle?

Tags: oracle, import, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server Compact `.sdf` database file, filled with data, that I need to import into an Oracle database in order to do some queries on it, and inserting the result in the actual tables of my db.

I need an utility to import the whole database like I do with Excel files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to import it like an excel file, just by uploading it to some sort of tool - SDF files are complex and change between SQL Server versions.

However, if you can get a local SQL Server up and running, so that you can connect to your SDF database using ODBC/JDBC, then you could try your luck with Oracle SQL Developer - either perform full migration like described [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/connect-sqlserver-1945229.html), or simply have two connections - one to oracle database and one to your local SQL server (look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/jdbc-migration-1923524.html) for howto and drivers) - and then you can copy tables verbatim from MSSQL connection to Oracle one, via right-click menu.

**Update:**

OK, I'm not familiar enough with MS SQL server variations, so the downvote was deserved. It turns out there's no way to connect to MS SQL CE via a JDBC driver since it's essentially just a set of DLLs and doesn't offer a net listener.

I think your best bet is to look for software that can export table structure and data from SQL CE database file to an SQL script - http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/ seems to be rather popular in answers here, on StackOverflow. If you have few tables and lots of data, you can recreate the structure in Oracle manually and simply use the INSERT statements generated by export. If your table structure is complex enough, though, it might be better to set up MS SQL Server Express, import your table structure and data there, and then proceed through SQLDeveloper way I described at the first part of answer.

Comment: The export also includes CREATE TABLE statements

Comment: CREATE TABLE statements for MS SQL server can fail in Oracle, due to syntax or datatype differences.